# rxgraph No module named gobject (OS X)

Tags: ros, rxtools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,  I am doing the tutorials on os x 10.6.7.  When I run rxgraph, in the ROS topics tutorial section I get the following error "No module named gobject"

I have went back and ran rosdep install rsxtools
and re-ran the roscpp_tutorials rospy_tutorials rxtools

Any ideas what is missing.  Appears to be python related, just not sure what.

Cheers

Joe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10404/rxgraph-no-module-named-gobject-(os-x)/) by [jpitz31](https://answers.ros.org/users/757/jpitz31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jpitz31](https://answers.ros.org/users/757/jpitz31/) on 2011-06-30**:
Thanks for all of the help.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-29**:
all I can think at this point is that your macports Python is not setup correctly somehow, but hard to debug over Q&A

**Comment by [jpitz31](https://answers.ros.org/users/757/jpitz31/) on 2011-06-29**:
ran sudo port install py26-gobject,

**Comment by [jpitz31](https://answers.ros.org/users/757/jpitz31/) on 2011-06-29**:
ran sudo port install py26-gobject, --->  Computing dependencies for py26-gobject
--->  Cleaning py26-gobject,  rxgraph still fails.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-28**:
what if you "port install py26-gobject"?

**Comment by [jpitz31](https://answers.ros.org/users/757/jpitz31/) on 2011-06-28**:
rosdep install rxgraph returns:  #No packages to install.  sudo port install py26-wxpython returns --->  Computing dependencies for py26-wxpython --->  Cleaning py26-wxpython. rxgraph still returns above error.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-28**:
Just realized that you're working with rxgraph.  Can you try "rosdep install rxgraph" instead?  I got thrown off by the original question description.  Basically, you need to install wxpython via macports.

**Comment by [jpitz31](https://answers.ros.org/users/757/jpitz31/) on 2011-06-27**:
kwc,  I went ahead and ran rosdep satisfy rxgraph and received the following:  sudo port install py26-pil graphviz.  I ran the install and re-ran the rosmake rxgraph.  But when I attempted to run rxgraph I still received the error "No module named gobject"  Joe

**Comment by [jpitz31](https://answers.ros.org/users/757/jpitz31/) on 2011-06-27**:
kwc,  I ran rosdep satisfy rxtools, rosdep returned #No packages to install, I then ran rosdep install rxtools,  return was also: #No packages to install

**Comment by [jpitz31](https://answers.ros.org/users/757/jpitz31/) on 2011-06-27**:
Thanks kwc,  When I get home I will run rosdep satisfy rxtools and post the results.  Joe

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-27**:
That's definitely a dependency installation issue.  Also, both your question tags and your question mention "rsxtools", when the correct invocation is "rosdep install rxtools".  Can you add the output of "rosdep satisfy rxtools" to your question (you can re-edit your question directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0